# Using sessions to grant user admin to page

Tags: php, validation, session, echo

I am doing an exercise for a class where a simple multi page website is made. One of the pages, the 'addeddit.php' page requires the user to be an administrator. However, if the user of the website is a broker then they should be denied access to this page.

I am unsure of how to correctly code the 'addedit.php' page.

I have a database saved with the username and password as well as a 'Y' or 'N' if they are an admin.
The php for my login page is as follows and I have added the $isadmin variable.

My 'addedit.php' code thus far is as follows:
session_start();

```
<?php
session_start();

if($isadmin==true){
header("location:addedit.php");
exit;
}
else
{
echo "Sorry, you must be an administrator to view this";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: How to correctly code my 'addedit.php' page to let admins use the page as normal, and to display the denied access message to brokers.

Comment: You are not storing isadmin value in session

Comment: please set session like this $_SESSION['admin']= $fetchresult['admin'];

Comment: How would I story the isadmin value in the session?

Answer (score 0):

Once try this please set session like this

```
$_SESSION['admin']= $fetchresult['admin'];
```

in the main page and in the  'addedit.php'  try like this..

```
<?php
        session_start();

        if($_SESSION['admin'] == 'Y'){
        header("location:addedit.php");
        exit;
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Sorry, you must be an administrator to view this";
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this here

```
$fetchresult = $result->fetchRow();
$userid = $fetchresult['username'];
$_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $fetchresult['admin'];
header("location:mainpage.php");
```

Now, addedit.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION)){
    if($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == true){
      header("location:addedit.php");
      exit;
    }
   else    {
      echo "Sorry, you must be an administrator to view this";
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my page is now saying this error "Notice: Undefined index: isAdmin in E:\Websites\addedit.php on line 5 Sorry, you must be an administrator to view this"

Comment: Not err, its just warning. can you tell what $fetchresult['admin'] is returning from db. Then I can help

Comment: I have corrected my typo mistake if($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == true) its 'isAdminn' not 'isadmiin'. Change this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the page that logs in the user you should store the values in the session, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
$_SESSION['isadmin'] = $isadmin;
```

Then on your addedit.php page you need to retrieve the value from the SESSION object, e.g.

```
$isadmin = $_SESSION['isadmin'];
```

Also be sure to check against the 'Y' flag if that's what you are storing in $isadmin, e.g.

```
if ($isadmin == 'Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change your else statement.**

```
else
{
    $fetchresult = $result->fetchRow();
    $userid = $fetchresult['username'];
    $isadmin = $fetchresult['admin'];

    if($isadmin=='N' || $isadmin='Y')//As you mention in the question 
            //That admin column of two value one is N and one is Y
     $_SESSION['admin']=$isadmin;
    header("location:mainpage.php");
}
?>
```

**Now your addedit.php look like this**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin']=$isadmin;//Only added this line
if($isadmin==TRUE){//rest of the code remain same. i  change only true to 
    //TRUE. But it should work with true as well
header("location:addedit.php");
exit;
}
else
{
echo "Sorry, you must be an administrator to view this";
}
}
?>
```